# Responsive A tags

Tags: html, css, button, text

Does anyone know how I can centre these two buttons so that they stay in the centre-bottom of the page no matter what size the user screen is?

```
<a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Back</a><a class="my-
 button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Next</a>

.my-button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #32CE87;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    left:30rem;
    right:10rem;
    position: relative;
    top:-4rem;
    width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.my-button:hover {
    background: #666;
    color: #c1e1e0;
}
```

Comment: `text-align: center` on the containing element of these two anchor tags will be enough to center horizontally, no need for `right` and `left` property values - unless, you are trying to align an *absolutely* positioned element. Consider editing your question to add more context and make your intention a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks  UncaughTypeError, I've managed to sort it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/nghpf7e7/

Need to wrap it in a div and apply a style:

```
.center-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this ,**

```
<div class="myContainer my-button">
 <a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Back</a>
 <a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

**css :**

```
.myContainer {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.my-button{
   display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.my-button::before{
  content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```